# Feel lost in the scheme of the reducibility of polynomials over $\Bbb Z$ or $\Bbb Q$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I'm studying abstract algebra. I have learned Eisenstein criterion, rational root test, Guass's lemma and so on. However, I can't see the scheme and the whole picture that these things plays the roles in. I think I should better directly ask here. I don't know where to start asking, so I list some questions below. Hope you can see what I'm stucking in. Need to be given the direction.

- Is the ultimate target here is that we want to tell whether a polynomial can be factored over $\Bbb Z$, or over $\Bbb Q$, or over $\Bbb R$, or over $\Bbb C$?
- Which do we really care about in the factorization? Integer coefficients polynomials, or rational coefficients? Or both?
- Is it a standard produre that whenever dealing with the (ir)reducibility problem of a polynomial of rational coefficients, we turn it into integer coefficient first? Why? Or is it vice versa?
- What is the importance or usage of Gauss's lemma?
- How about reducibility over $\Bbb R$ or $\Bbb C$ when there're no many tools can be used as in the $\Bbb Q[x]$?

Comment: What we care about really depends on what problem we are trying to solve. I understand how you feel: it often happens that one is given a lot of mathematical instruments (theorems) without knowing why he should care or what he should do with them. But don't desist: these theorems do have applications (the best way to see it is to find some nice, interesting exercises, which is not always easy to do, above all at the beginning). Note that if a polynomial factors over $\mathbb{Z}$, it also factors over all the rings that contain $\mathbb{Z}$. So the other one is the direction you usually want.

Comment: A polynomial (with coefficients in $\Bbb C$) can **always** be decomposed into linear factors in $\Bbb C$, as $\Bbb C$ is an algebraically closed field.

Comment: Before I meant: "factors over $\mathbb{Z}$ with factors that are not just constants".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Warning: my bullet points are not isomorphic to yours!

- If a polynomial factors over a smaller field, then it also factors in the bigger ones above (for general rings, this is more tricky: $ax^2+a$ factors over $\mathbb{Z}$ as $a(x^2+1)$ for all $a\neq 0,\pm1$ (since $a$ is not a unit), but in $\mathbb{R}$ it is irreducible, because $a$ is a unit). Also, if a polynomial has a zero in a smaller ring, then it also has (the same) zero in the bigger rings above.
- Being irreducible doesn't coincide with having no zeros, in general. For example, $(x^2+1)(x^2+1)$ is reducible over anything, but it doesn't have a zero in $\mathbb{R}$. Conversely, $x$ is always irreducible but it always has a zero. Nevertheless, the two things are related: for instance, if $F$ is a field and $P(x) \in F[x]$ is a polynomial with degree greater than one that has a zero in $F$, then $P$ is reducible (this comes from division with remainder of polynomials).
- Integers are also rational numbers. So integer coefficient polynomials are also rational coefficient polynomials. But it is also true that a polynomial with rational coefficients is just a rational multiple of a polynomial with integer coefficients (just clear the denominators), and their zeros coincide (and the zeros are usually the most interesting thing). Irreducibility over $\mathbb{Q}$ implies irreducibility over $\mathbb{Z}$, if the polynomial is primitive. One does not immediately see why the converse should be true, but it is, by Gauss lemma! So irreducibility over $\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ is the same for primitive polynomials. Why do we consider only primitive polynomials? For the reason mentioned above: if you can divide the polynomial by some integer $a\neq 0,\pm 1$, then it is reducible over $\mathbb{Z}$, but not necessarily over $\mathbb{Q}$. But since roots don't depend on a division by a constant factor $a$, note that Gauss lemma implies that a polynomial with integer coefficients and degree greater than one has an integer root if and only if it has a rational root! That's amazing!
- What I find very helpful is to always see any (complex) polynomial of degree $n$ as $u(x-\alpha_1)\dots(x-\alpha_n)$, where $u$ is some complex number and the $\alpha_i$ are the roots (not necessarily distinct). This is always possible, since $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically close (maybe you have not learnt it yet, but it is true and there are many very beautiful proofs of this fact).
- It is easier to check irreducibility in $\mathbb{Z}$ than in $\mathbb{Q}$, that's why you often do so.
- As I already said, polynomials over $\mathbb{C}$ always have a very easy form. In $\mathbb{R}$ you have that irreducible polynomials always have degree at most $2$. This comes from the fact that if $\alpha$ is a complex root of some real polynomial, then also $\overline{\alpha}$ is (why?). So let $P$ be any real polynomial that has at least a non-real root. Then it is divisible by $(x-\alpha)(x-\overline{\alpha})=x^2 + |\alpha|^2-2xRe(\alpha)$, which is a real polynomial. In particular, if it has degree at least $3$, it is not irreducible.

Many things will become clearer when you will do some field theory: there irreducibility of polynomials becomes very important. Also at this stage, doing some exercises involving irreducibility criteria will certainly clarify things.

Comment: Thanks. This is very helpful! Still digesting. Since I find that you're online now, I want to ask a little question. Can I say that, it may be not interesting to study whether a polynomial factors over "$\Bbb Z$" in the practical problem (since $\Bbb Z$ is too "small", and studying its reducibility over fields like $\Bbb Q,~\Bbb R,~\Bbb C$ is more useful, from our experience in high school algebra), however, studying whether it factors over $\Bbb Q$ turns out to be somewhat reduce to the problem that whether it factors over "$\Bbb Z$"?

Comment: @Eric It is actually more interesting to see when a polynomial factors over $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Q}$, because it is harder than for $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ (there the theory of polynomials is easier). But of course, it depends on what you are doing. Number theory is often concerned with integers and rationals, analysis just does not care and only wants real or complex things (very badly said)

Comment: Every complex polynomial of degree at least $2$ factors over $\mathbb{C}$ and every real polynomial of degree at least $3$ factors over $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: I see. I'm not sure I understand the third bullet. First let me check a little point that in the sentence "*Irreducibility over $\Bbb Q$ implies irreducibility over $\Bbb Z$, if the polynomial is primitive.*"  I think you mean "for **an integer coefficient** polynomial $f(x)$, suppose $f(x)$ is primitive, then $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$ iff $f(x)$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Z$" right? (By the standard definition,) we cannot talk about whether, say $\frac{1}{3}x^2+1$ is primitive, so when we say a polynomial is primitive, we implicity require that it is of integer coefficient?

Comment: Exactly. Let's suppose $f$ is primitive (with integers coefficients, but it is superfluous to say it, it is implicit). Then if it factors over $\mathbb{Z}$ it clearly also factors over $\mathbb{Q}$ (since the two factors must have degree at least 1 (otherwise $f$ would not be primitive), so they are not constants). The other direction is implied by the Gauss lemma (I am not sure which version you had).

Comment: Yes, I'm also thinking about your words about Gauss lemma. :P The Gauss lemma I have is "the product of two primitive polynomials is primitive." And I have its collary: "If a integer coefficients polynomial $f(x)$ is reducible over $\Bbb Q$, then it is reducible over $\Bbb Z$." Fortunately, I can understand the proofs of them. However, is this direction (being reducible over $\Bbb Q\Rightarrow$ being reducible over $\Bbb Z$) useful in practice? I can't imagine ...

Comment: ... the case that it is more easy for us to check whether a polynomial factors over $\Bbb Q$ than factors over $\Bbb Z$ (I *roughly* guess that this is one reason we need Eisenstein criterion for irreducibility over $\Bbb Q$?). Hmm... maybe you had already answered in the post, but I need to think more about it.

Comment: What we use in practice now is exactly the corollary you mentioned. It is useful because to check irreducibility over $\mathbb{Z}$ is easier than over $\mathbb{Q}$, in general, since there are only finitely many ways in which you can write an integer as a product of other integers. For instance, you see that $x^2+3x+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}$ because otherwise it would be of the form $(x-a)(x-b)$ and the integers $a$ and $b$ would satisfy $ab=1, a+b=-3$, which is clearly not possible for integers. Also, you use Gauss lemma to prove the Eisenstein criterion, I think.

Comment: Note: "irreducible over $\mathbb{Z} \ \Rightarrow \ $ irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}$" is equivalent to "reducible over $\mathbb{Q} \ \Rightarrow \ $ reducible over $\mathbb{Z}$"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71642/discussion-between-57jimmy-and-eric).

Answer (score 1):

What we really care about depends, as always, on our viewpoint, i.e., on the problems we want to solve. In number theory, polynomials with integer and rational coefficients are very interesting, and finding roots is a famous, old question going back to ["Diophantos"](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantos_von_Alexandria). To solve Diophantine equations, like $x^n+y^n=z^n$, we need at least some algebraic number theory, e.g., the ring of integers of the cyclotomic field $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$. For Dedekind rings, and commutative rings in general, we need the basics from commutative algebra, e.g., irreducible and prime elements, respectively ideals. So one reason to study this, comes from this motivation. Cyclotomic fields are very important examples of number fields, and cyclotomic polynomials very important examples of irreducible polynomials, you were asking about. The name of Gauss appearing in this context, is directing towards number theory, I would say:)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one story: not the only one, but a very common one.

Often we are interested in the factorisation of a polynomial $f\in\mathbb{Q}[X]$.

Multiplying by any $c\in\mathbb{Q}$ doesn't change anything, so we can clear the fractions and suppose $f\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$, although we are still interested in factorisations in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$.

Gauss's Lemma tells us how factorisations in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$ relate to factorisations in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$, so our focus moves to such factorisations.

Now Eisenstein's Criterion (and the ideas behind it) relate the factorisations of $f\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$ in $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ with the factorisations of $\bar{f}\in\mathbb{Z}_p[X]$ in $\mathbb{Z}_p[X]$, a potentially "easier" problem.